# Mobile Application using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, mobile

I want to develop a small 4 screens mobile application.

The technology stack that i want to use is AngularJS, I am good with C#,
I searched few times and could not find any examples using AngularJS.

The mobile app should be compatible in iPhone, Android, Windows 8.

What are all the technologies that i need to use.

Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Take a look @ Ionic (http://ionicframework.com/) – Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps. Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am having a positive experience with this:

https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter

It lets me use jQuery Mobile while respecting the AngularJS semantics and using its constructs.

Answer (score 39):

You should take a look at the Angular-mobile-nav plugin on github:

https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav.

It is a very simple plugin to include with angular.js. Importantly the demo files that are included provide a pretty good idea of how to get started, although you do still need to know how Angular interacts with its modules, controllers and routes.

You can see the demo app here:

http://ajoslin.github.com/angular-mobile-nav/

I've just moved from jQuery-mobile to angular.js and angular-mobile-nav because it provides me with a much nicer way to build the app and bind data within the views, without hijacking the DOM.

Comment: Just a heads up, this plugin is no longer being updated and has been superseded by this one as of July 2013: https://github.com/opitzconsulting/angular-jqm

Comment: Why are adapters actually needed?
Is there anything flawed or missing in angular.js itself, for using it for mobile browsers? I'd really love to know this.

Comment: @matt they're not, it's just to make it look more "native".  ionicframework is another newer angular-based framework that works well for a native look.